# Publish a package to Github using Semantic-release

Tags: node.js, npm, github-actions, github-package-registry, semantic-release

Update2: I spent way to many hours trying to make this work, it has been tiring and frustrating, I am now doing everything manually. I do the release manually and I publish the package locally with my terminal, as it works fine with no problem.
I tried all the possible fixes, but there is no way to make this thing work, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Update: Does the fact that the package is private from our org makes any difference? I looked at all the tutorials, and I used github action template for publishing github actions and still no results, this is very frustrating, how come looks so easy in the tutorial? Everything I try is failing, although it publishes the packages, which is even weird.
Here is the code from github:

```
  publish-gpr:
    needs: release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18
          registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/
      - run: yarn
      - run: yarn publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

I am trying to publish a private package to Github using semantic-release
This is my workflow file

```
name: Release
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

permissions:
  contents: read # for checkout

jobs:
  release:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions: write-all
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 'lts/*'
          registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
          scope: '@scope' // private scope 

      - name: Get yarn cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        id: yarn-cache
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/workflows/**.yml') }}

      - name: Install Node.js dependencies
        if: steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile

      - name: Run linting
        run: yarn lint

      - name: Release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: yarn semantic-release

      - name: Publish to Github
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
        run: yarn publish
```

But when I run it, the release is created correctly but the package is not published, I get an error:

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://npm.pkg.github.com/
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

Is getting quite frustrating as I don't get why, I literally took the code from github and semantic-release tutorials. I do not want to publish to npm, but only to github for my team (@scope is replaced with our org name)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is actually publishing the package, but still the CI workflow fails, I am kinda of desperate, I understand I need to create a .npmrc file in the workflow but how?

Comment: Could you add to permissions `packages: write`?

Comment: I added but nothing. Here is an update version, taken straight from github action templates ...
```

  publish-gpr:
    needs: release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18
          registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/
      - run: yarn
      - run: yarn publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}

```

Comment: See: https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/49#issuecomment-1293249466

Comment: I am using @semantic-release/github should this publish the package without me publishing it manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to publish a package using Semantic Release, then you don't have to manually publish with yarn publish. semantic-release/npm has a wrapper around the publish command and it should handle that for you assuming its `verifyConditions` step passes. If it failed, the log would be slightly different. You could maybe add your semantic.release.js configuration up there.
Regarding how to create or write a .npmrc file, the action `actions/setup-node@v3` already does that for you on the machine that runs this but if you needed to do it yourself which is okay, add a `.npmrc` file and paste in your config such as

```bash
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN}
@scope:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```